# PLL Simulink Out

Tags: signal-analysis, pll, simulink

I am trying to create a sine wave in PLL output with Simulink.
But I get a square wave from the VCO block even though PFD, charge pump and loop filter outputs are correct. The VCO block says that only square wave is given as output in Matlab Help. It is written that only square wave is obtained, but theoretically PLL should be able to produce a sine wave. Is it because you can't generate sines because I misinterpreted the square wave in the VCO output?

I don't know how to create the sine output. I can't understand why the output is always square. What exactly do I need to do to the PLL output signal afterwards? You can specify the points you want me to explain on. If I have misunderstood the use of this block, I would appreciate it if you correct me and tell me how to achieve the correct result.

I am attaching the simulink design as an example.
Also, I used the provided example of MATLAB for this.

[image]

Here is the PLL out:

[image]

Comment: If The Mathworks is telling you it only has a square wave out, they're probably telling the truth.  If you need a sine wave out, then depending on the frequency range you need you should either filter the square wave, make your own VCO that has sine wave out, or dig through the available blocks and see if there's a sine-output VCO.

Comment: @TimWescott thank you for your answer. Should we use the wave for analysis instead of generating it for this block? I'm curious about your opinion. 
Honestly, even if I enter the parameters, I can't get the correct results.